# Android ListView swipe to dismiss

Tags: android

I'm writing an Android app in which I use a ListView. On each row in the ListView I have a TextView in which I am putting text with HTML tags and some of those tags are links. In order to visualize the text correctly and to use the links when I click on them I had to extend SimpleCursorAdapter. This is the code for my Adapter.

```
public class SimpleHtmlCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

public SimpleHtmlCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
}

@Override
public void setViewText(TextView view, String text) {

    view.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);

    // This makes the links in the TextView clickable
    view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
```

}

Since I want a swipe to dismiss functionality for the ListView I used [This SwipeToDismiss implementation](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss/blob/master/src/com/example/android/swipedismiss/SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.java). But the problem is that if I use "view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());" the swiping is not working. On the other hand, if I remove that line of code, the swipe gesture works and list rows are dismissed perfectly but I can't use the links in the TextView (nothing happens when i click on them).

Could you give me an idea how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its very Easy Use this Tutorial of Github.

[Link to Github](https://github.com/krishjlk/android-listview-swipe-delete-example-sample-tuorial)

This Will help to you.